# How to disable bootstrap from Yii2 basic?

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I removed `yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap` from `composer.json` and update composer, removed `bootstrap` from `assets/AppAsset.php`, but still loads bootstrap CSS and JS!
When I remove `<?php $this->head() ?>` from layout, CSS doesn't load, but `bootstrap.js` is loaded!

How to remove all bootstrap assets from Yii2 basic app?

Comment: Are you're using some widgets/packages which depends on bootstrap? Show content of your `composer.json`.

Comment: I remember to install and try a basic app template from github with bootstrap already striped away but can't find it anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `web.php` add this code

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
            'js'=>[]
        ],
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
            'js'=>[]
        ],
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
            'css' => [],
        ],

    ],
],
```

and remove this line in AppAsset.php

```
public $depends = [
   'yii\web\YiiAsset',              #REMOVE
   'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',  #REMOVE
];
```

Comment: you can add `sourcePath=>null` in `bundles` to make sure they don't look into the `@bower` directory to load the scripts, removing the lines from `AppAsset` is not compulsory for disabling bootstrap js and css loading